# Can I access the Google Calendar API *directly* from javascript running in an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-calendar-api

I want to get started with the Google Calendar API and my idea was to just setup a simple HTML site I can directly open in the browser.
From this site I want to for example create an event in Google Calendar.

Is this possible (and how), or can I only access the Google Calendar API from a server?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but not so well supported by google. If you have a quick look at google developers, you'll find what you need. Including [a quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js) and [how to insert an event](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert).

Also mind the authorizations you'll need `calendar` instead of `calendar.readonly`